# Can you register multiple ModelAdmins for a Model? Alternatives?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Say I have the Django model class:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
 bar = models.CharField()
 baz = models.CharField()
```

and the ModelAdmins:

```
class Foo_Admin_1(admin.ModelAdmin):
 list_display = ['id','bar']

class Foo_Admin_2(admin.ModelAdmin):
 list_display = ['id','baz']
```

is there any way to register both ModelAdmins so that they show up under the Django Admin interface?

I tried:

```
admin.site.register(Foo,Foo_Admin_1)
admin.site.register(Foo,Foo_Admin_2)
```

but I get the error:

```
The model Foo is already registered
```

Any suggestions?

If not, are there alternative ways to (dynamically) control the fields shown in the ModelAdmin change list view?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create an empty proxy subclass and register it instead:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.CharField()
    baz = models.CharField()

# admin.py
class FooProxy(Foo):
    class Meta:
        proxy=True

admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin1)
admin.site.register(FooProxy, FooAdmin2)
```

Comment: Yep, I was able to do exactly what I needed using this method, thanks again